# Git Extensions Replace tracking reference

Tags: git, git-extensions

Hi everyone I am currently investigating GIT and Git Extensions I have an issue I am struggling with at present and can't seem to find any information.

Could someone please tell me what effect selecting the Replace tracking reference option has when performing a push using the Git Extensions GUI.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: See https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1481

Answer (score 2):

If you push to a branch that is not the current remote tracking branch with this option checked, then the push will also change the remote tracking branch of your current branch.

The result is that next time you push, the push dialog remembers which branch you pushed to last time (the push dialog opens with the remote tracking branch as the "to" branch).

Answer (score 1):

When you add a tracking reference (or more commonly called a remote tracking branch) you create a local pointer to the remote's branch.  In git cmd line, it'll show you regular branches in green, remote tracking branches in red.  In Git Extensions the colors are unfortunately reversed.  Why is this helpful?  It shows you not only where you think these branches are but also where the other repository thinks they are (as of the last time you pulled or fetched).